# Problem deleting broken files on external drive

Tags: files, external-hdd

i have a 500gb external drive (Maxtor One Touch) some days ago i moved some files from the destkop to it.
the operation failed (on the disk there are only 4 or 5 incomplete files ) and i can't remove those files.
i tried through nautilus and from the command line but nothing..
any idea?
thanks

Comment: Please attach the drive to your computer, open a terminal and paste the output of the command `mount` (use http://paste.ubuntu.com if it's too long).

Comment: Can you tell us what you did on the command line? Did you try doing a disk check on the external drive? And please add what format your drive is in (e.g. EXT4, EXT3, XFS, NTFS, FAT32, EXFAT, etc).

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/554480/ here the output of the command the filesystem is NTFS. what do you mean for disk check? (with all the  other stuff on it the disk works well) on the command line i tryed to remove files with rm -f as normal(buzz) user and as root

Comment: Please check the disk as it might have errors. If you have windows let windows check it.

Comment: how can i do it with ubuntu?

Comment: The disk is mounted in 'rw' mode, so now we at least know that it wasn't a problem with a read-only mounted disk. Do you get any error messages when trying to remove the files on the command line (as user/with `sudo`)?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/554780/ i tryed ls -l command on the directory that contains the broken files there's something strange.. when i try to cancel i get only a generic impossible delete file error

Comment: Try using testdisk to check for errors, though it never actually did anything for me...

Answer (score 2):

Unmount the drive and run `sudo fsck /dev/sdb1 -f` , (seems sdb1 is the partition you want to check).
If it's a NTFS partition, run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1`

Comment: Please note that in the case of a NTFS partition, ntfsfix will only fix BIG errors or inconsistencies, and will mark it for automatic chkdsk next time (in Windows).

Comment: As you can see from the `mount` output, the drive is mounted 'rw' (read/write) - if there were filesystem errors, it wouldn't mount it at all or only as 'ro' (read-only).

Comment: here there is the output of sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 http://paste.ubuntu.com/554784/

Comment: and after that have you run `chkdsk` on it?

Comment: @htorque really? it seems quite possible there are errors that won't be detected at mount time, or that wouldn't cause it to be remounted readonly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to hook it up to a different computer you can delete them that way or disk defragmentate the hard drive on a Windows computer. I have some Maxtor external hard drives, and they aren't the best, unfortunately, but hooking it up to a different computer and deleting them that way usually works for me